# where id IN ("1,2,3,4") - реально ли в Mysql?

Tags: mysql

В постгрессе вроде есть возможность разбить строку по разделителям и получить массив, пригодный для оператора IN

А как можно в mysql это сделать? Т.е. нужно что бы это сработало:

```
where id IN ("1,2,3,4")
```

Comment: Если у вас данные хранятся в таком виде, то необходимо нормализовать базу данных, а не работать таким образом.

Comment: Первая мыль должна быть не как мне *это* сделать, а как мне *этого* избежать.

Answer (score 3):

Никаких проблем с этим в mysql быть не должно. Только ты в своём примере зря все id в одни кавычки взял, так работать не будет, они как одна строка воспринимаются.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id IN ("2","19","20");
```

а для чисел можно вообще без кавычек

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE id IN (2,19,20);
```

Comment: Как я понял, он хочет распарсить это. прямо в mysql

Comment: Я перефразирую вопрос: есть строка с значениями разделенными запятой "1,2,3,4", как ее разбить на отдельные части, что бы использовать в операторе IN.

Comment: Ааа, кажется понял чего хочет автор вопроса. У него уже есть строка в кавычках (полученная откуда-то) и он хочет использовать её как массив. В гугле есть какие-то варианты (например http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471914/can-you-split-explode-a-field-in-a-mysql-query). Но, ИМХО, если понадобилось что-то подобное то ты используешь SQL неправильно. В реляционной модели данных массивы значений не должны храниться как строки.

Comment: Есть ещё такие извращения, как раз почти что нужно: http://www.montrealseocompany.com/2012/04/17/mysql-split-string-into-rows-function/ Но в целом - да, очень плохая идея.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией MySQL [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
where FIND_IN_SET(id, "1,2,3,4")
```