# Как можно в php where id IN (“1,2,3,4”)

Tags: php, mysql, count

В постгрессе вроде есть возможность разбить строку по разделителям и получить массив, пригодный для оператора IN

А как можно в php это сделать? заранее спасибо.

```
$post_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `forum` WHERE `type` = 't' AND `refid` = '" . $res['id'] . "'");
 while ($post_count = mysql_fetch_assoc($post_query)) {
 $postsql = $post_count['id'].',';
 $post_total = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `forum` WHERE `refid` = '".$re['id']."' "),0);
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php

Comment: например вставить прямо в тексте внутрь IN список, разумеется без кавычек и убедившись, в невозможности sql-инъекций (проверив корректность значений)

Comment: Вопрос отличающийся 1 словом  :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413290/where-id-in-1-2-3-4-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-mysql?rq=1

Comment: Объясни, что тебе надо посчитать, и тебе покажут, как всеь этот ужас заменить на 1 запрос

Comment: извините, я здесь первый раз, спасибо за помог.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала надо разбить строку в массив, через explode. Потом сгенерить строку с плейсхолдерами по количеству элментов в массиве, и потом забиндить массив.

```
$arr = explode(",","1,2,3");
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($in)";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute($arr);
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Пример [отсюда](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in)

Если же говорить о конкретном коде, то во-первых, функции mysql_query() в РНР больше не существует, а во-вторых, весь этот ужас делается одним запросом:

```
SELECT f1.*, count(*) FROM forum f1 JOIN forum f2 ON f2.refid=f1.refid
WHERE type='t'
GROUP BY f1. refid
```

Comment: <code>
$test = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `forum` WHERE `refid` IN (';
            $post_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `forum` WHERE `refid` = '".$re['id']."' ");
            while ($postlar = mysql_fetch_assoc($post_query)) {
                $test .= $postlar['id'].',';
            }
            $test .= ')';
            $postlar_soni = mysql_result(mysql_query(str_replace(',)', ')', $test)),0);
</code>